# bibliographystyle with comma after journal name (i.e., just before volume)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Does anybody know of a `\bibliographystyle` exactly like `chicago`, however with a comma **after** the journal name just before the volume? Or is there an easy way to implement a comma in the `chicago.bst` file?

Like:

> Ross, M. L. (2001). Does oil hinder
>   democracy? World Politics, 53(3),
>   325–361.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy way. Just edit two lines in the `format.jour.vol` function, which begins on line 695 of `chicago.bst`:

```
FUNCTION {format.jour.vol}
{ journal empty$
    { "no journal in " cite$ * warning$
      "" }
    { journal emphasize.space }
    if$
  number empty$
    { volume empty$
       { "no number and no volume in " cite$ * warning$
         "" * }
       { ", {\em " * Volume * "}" * }  % EDIT: added comma, replaced non-breaking space
      if$
    }
    { volume empty$
      {"no volume for " cite$ * warning$
       "~(" * number * ")" * }
      { ", " *    % EDIT: added comma, replaced non-breaking space
        volume emphasize.space
        "(" * number * ")" * * }
      if$
    }
```

If you'd prefer not to have any linebreaks between the journal name and volume number, just replace the space following the comma with a non-breaking space (`~`). You might want to save this as a new file, say:

```
texmf-local/bibtex/bst/mychicago/mychicago.bst
```

(where `texmf-local` is the path to your TeX installation) and then update the TeX file index.